# Schtasks delete userprofile

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-task

I have two scripts,
One of them in batch for a weekly task schedule
task_del_user.cmd

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC weekly /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI /TN MyDailyDelete /ST 15:00:00 /TR "Powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\del_userprofile.ps1" /RU "Admin" /RP "admin1"
```

And the second one in powershell to delete userprofile older than x days
del_userprofile.ps1

```
# Program to delete user profiles through Powershell older than 30 days

# User profiles older than today's date - $ of days will be deleted
$numberOfDays = 30

# Number of digits in local path string to just after C:\users\
$pos = 9

# Get all user profiles where the last log on time is older than the current date - $numberOfDays
$profileStructsToRemove = Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile |
    Where-Object {$_.LastUseTime -lt $(Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-$numberOfDays) } |
    Where-Object {$_.LocalPath.ToUpper() -ne 'C:\USERS\ADMINISTRATOR'} |
    Where-Object {$_.LocalPath.ToUpper() -ne 'C:\USERS\PUBLIC'}
    Where-Object {$_.LocalPath.ToUpper() -ne 'C:\USERS\Default'}

foreach ($struct in $profileStructsToRemove)
{
    $userProfileToDelete = $struct.LocalPath.Substring($pos, $struct.LocalPath.Length - $pos)
    Write-Host "Currently deleting profile...$userProfileToDelete..."
    (Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -Filter "localpath='C:\\Users\\$userProfileToDelete'").Delete()
}
```

I can do it successfully on my account, 
but I can't apply it on a session without administration rights, 
Can you please help me.

Comment: Why are you saying it is due to lack of administrator privileges? Are you receiving an error 5/access denied?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add `/RL HIGHEST` to the schtasks /CREATE command. Default is LIMITED.

Comment: I've already tried it, it didn't work